# wordpress: add modal box manually to header.php

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i want to add the following code to my wordpress header.php to open up a modal box, when I click on a button (in this case i can not usw any plugin) therefore i wan to do it like on this page:

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal

**CSS**

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

but the problem is i only get the error:

"type error: btn is null

but my button element was implemented directly at the body, so why it could be not found???

thanks for any help or hints!

greetings

Alex

Comment: use script tag below your html code .

Comment: or use jquery ready

Comment: i have already added my ja code into some script tag! and the script tag part is into my head part

Comment: what u mean with jquery ready?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_ready.asp

Comment: not even that works into my wordpress header.php code :(

Comment: remove script tag from head part to bottom of body .

Comment: ok i will try it!

Comment: no also doesnt work

Comment: try like that example in w3schools

Comment: ok it works ;) thank u very much!

Comment: but how can I toggle a login form, thats my goal! but i will google now!